# Android adapter - is memory leak possible?

Tags: android, memory-leaks, android-recyclerview

I'm just making my own implementation of `RecyclerView.Adapter` and I'm not sure whether I can get memory leaks or not.

Problem is, that I'm filling Adapter with data from Database via Loader Manager `activity.getLoaderManager().initLoader()`

All I want is that Activity don't need to handle all requests adapter. So I'm making instance of Adapter with activity and loader ID stored as local variable. Will that make any leak? If yes should I use `WeekReference` or some other approach?

Answer (score 1):

From your descrition it looks like you have no leak, adapter will be referenced only by your Activity and RecyclerView. RecyclerView will be also referenced only by your activity - so garbage collector will free this memory. To make sure use memory analysis tools like android studio [Allocation Tracker](http://developer.android.com/tools/studio/index.html#alloc-tracker).

Answer (score 0):

Well, I'm currently working with RecyclerView and lot of images, and I have never have memory leak, RecyclerView is optimized version of ListView and it works good in my case with lot of images. I'm using `WeakRefernce`.

Please give some code to check.

Answer (score 0):

Well, because you didn't paste your code there so it's hard for my help to resolve your issue.
But I can give you an option is using this library to check memory leak 
https://github.com/square/leakcanary
Easy to use. Reply me if you need anything.